# Batch - Search text file for specified string and if found set variable to 1

Tags: variables, search, for-loop, batch-file

I can't seem to find a answer for this, all the questions seem focused on setting whats found in the text file as the variable. I just want to see if the string I have provided exists anywhere in the text file. (on its own line, not sharing a line with another string)

An example:

%usrname%= fish

%banfile%= is just a text file with NOTHING in it.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ('find /c /i "%usrname%" "%banfile%"') do set banned=1
```

Even with nothing in the text file, it still sets %banned%=1. I want it to set the variable %banned%=1 only if it finds one or more of the string "fish" inside the text file.

I am just beginning to understand the `for` command, so for most people this is probably going to be very simple. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need a `for` loop for this:

```
find /i "%usrname%" "%banfile%" >nul 2>&1&&set /a banned=1 || set /a banned=0
echo %banned%
```

Answer (score 1):

To find `fish` on a line that has no other text, you can use this:

```
@echo off
set "usrname=fish"
set "banfile=c:\folder\file.txt"
set "banned="
findstr /i /r "^%usrname%$" "%banfile%" >nul && set banned=1
```

The /i makes it case insensitive and it will find `fish` on a line by itself, anywhere in the file.