# Set variables in batch from part of text file

Tags: batch-file

im looking for for a method to set variables from **part** of a text. I Have a .txt file where is something like this

```
part of text
part of text
part of text
part of text
password: 123456
part of text
```

how can i get a variable 123456 from this file?

I try to use

```
set var1=<"C:Windows\text.txt"
```

but it is not working

Any idea mate?

Comment: there are already a lot of duplicates: [How to read file contents into a variable in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068929/995714), [Windows Batch: Set Variables from Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5886334/995714), [Set variable equal to a number in a text file Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27094750/995714), [How can I load the contents of a text file into a batch file variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134001/995714)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text in file and set it as a variable. Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198458/find-text-in-file-and-set-it-as-a-variable-batch-file)

Comment: [Find string in text file and set variable with windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30435794/995714), [Find text in file and set it as a variable. Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22198458/995714), [Batch - Search text file for specified string and if found set variable to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18170217/995714)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are working in a cmd shell on windows, this command from the command line may solve your question

```
for /F  "tokens=2"  %i in ('findstr "password: " "C:Windows\text.txt"') do set var1=%i
```

while this is if you  need the variable in a batch file (where percentage symbols need to be duplicated):

```
for /F  "tokens=2"  %%i in ('findstr "password: " "C:Windows\text.txt"') do set var1=%%i
```

for further info I suggest you to read the help message of the for command with

```
for /?
```

(especially the first example => FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in ...)